# Play audio url with exoplayer new media 3

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm learning about the new media3 and `ExoPlayer` through https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#0

The docs are really good. However, the audio starts playing immediately the activity is launched.

I want to only play the song when it is clicked on the `RecyclerView`. I have each song uri.

```kotlin
     musicAdapter = MusicAdapter(onClickListener = MusicAdapter.OnMusicClickListener{uri->

         //I want to play the song here using the uri with exoplayer media3 

        })
```

From the docs, the player is initialised immediately the activity starts like this:

```kotlin
    val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(requireContext()).apply {
            setParameters(buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd())
        }

     player = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .build()
            .also { exoPlayer ->
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(getString(R.string.media_url_mp3))
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                exoPlayer.seekTo(currentItem, playbackPosition)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the playWhenReady attribute to false it basically tells exoplayer to not play the video/audio as soon as it is loaded.
Then you can manually call the player.play() function inside the onClickHandler.

A simple example is this :-

```
    val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this).apply {
            setParameters(buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd())
        }

     player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .build()
            .apply {
                playWhenReady = false
     }

     musicAdapter = MusicAdapter(onClickListener = MusicAdapter.OnMusicClickListener{uri->
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)

               player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
               player.prepare()
               player.play()

        })
```

Note: I have also considered uri variable of type Uri not of String.